# What is the right way to loop over a pandas dataframe and apply a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through a list of dictionaries, comparing a value to a pair of columns in a Pandas dataframe and adding a value to a third column under a certain condition.

My list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
dict_list = [{'type': 'highlight', 'id': 0, 'page_number': 4, 'location_number': 40, 'content': 'Foo'}, {'type': 'highlight', 'id': 1, 'page_number': 12, 'location_number': 96, 'content': 'Bar'}, {'type': 'highlight', 'id': 2, 'page_number': 128, 'location_number': 898, 'content': 'Some stuff'}]
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    start    end  note_count
1       1    100           0
2     101    200           0
3     201    300           0
```

For each dictionary, I want to pull the "page_number" value and compare it to the "start" and "end" columns in the dataframe rows. If page_number is within the range of those two values in a row, I want to +1 to the "note_count" column for that row. This is my current code:

```
for dict in dict_list:
    page_number = dict['page_number']
    for index, row in ventile_frame.iterrows():
        ventile_frame["note_count"][(ventile_frame["start"] <= page_number) & (ventile_frame["end"] >= page_number)] += 1
print (ventile_frame)
```

I would expect to see a result like this.

```
    start    end  note_count
1       1    100           2
2     101    200           1
3     201    300           0
```

Instead, I am seeing this.

```
    start    end  note_count
1       1    100           9
2     101    200           0
3     201    300           0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate on the rows of `ventile_frame` - and that's the beauty of it!

`(ventile_frame["start"] <= page_number) & (ventile_frame["end"] >= page_number)` will produce a boolean mask indicating whether `page_number` is within the range of each row. Try it with a fixed value for `page_number` to understand what's going on:

```py
print((ventile_frame["start"] <= 4) & (ventile_frame["end"] >= 4))
```

Bottom line is, you just need to iterate on the dicts:

```py
for single_dict in dict_list:
    page_number = single_dict['page_number']
    ventile_frame["note_count"][(ventile_frame["start"] <= page_number) & (ventile_frame["end"] >= page_number)] += 1
print (ventile_frame)
```

Note that I replaced `dict` by `single_dict` in the above code, it's best to avoid shadowing built-in python names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```
m=pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.start,df.end, 'both')
#output-> IntervalIndex([[1, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300]],
          #closed='both',
          #dtype='interval[int64]')
n=m.set_index(s).loc[m['page_number']].groupby(level=0)['page_number'].count()
n.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([n.index])
```

---

```
final=df.set_index(['start','end']).assign(new_note_count=n).reset_index()
final['new_note_count']=final['new_note_count'].fillna(0)
```

---

Output:

```
   start  end  note_count  new_note_count
0      1  100           0             2.0
1    101  200           0             1.0
2    201  300           0             0.0
```

Details:
Once we have the index as interval , set index of `m` and `.loc[]` the `page_number`

```
print(m.set_index(s).loc[m['page_number']])
```

---

```
                 type  id  page_number  location_number content
[1, 100]    highlight   0            4               40     Foo
[1, 100]    highlight   0            4               40     Foo
[101, 200]  highlight   1           12               96     Bar
```

Then using `groupby()` get counts, convert to Multiindex and assign it back.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

**first create a series with the numbers of pages contained in the dictionary:**

```
page_serie=pd.Series([dict_t['page_number'] for dict_t in dict_list])
print(page_serie)

0      4
1     12
2    128
dtype: int64
```

---

**Then, 
for each row of your dataframe you determine if the values ​​of the series are between `'start'` and `'end'` and the sums**

```
df['note_count']=df.apply(lambda x: page_serie.between(x['start'],x['end']),axis=1).sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   start  end  note_count 
1      1  100           2 
2    101  200           1 
3    201  300           0
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reponse!